# Proper copy-pasteable single quotes in listing

Tags: listings, quoting, copy-paste

Yes, I know this is VERY similar to previous questions but my specific problem seems to be unaddressed.

No matter what I do I always end up with code that copy-pastes as such:
[image: Copying from the latex listing]
[image: Pasted in notepad++]

Notice the unwanted line break that has mysteriously appeared during the copy-paste!

My current listing settings are as follows:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\lstset{
    language = Matlab,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=single,
    upquote=true,
}
```

So, how to have proper copy-pasteable single quotes?

Comment: Show a complete example, not only a snippet.

Comment: It works fine for me. I think this might be an viewer thing. Which viewer are you using? Also, which engine? (and also, a complete example as Ulrike said)